# Did Wade Wilson have mutant powers before being turned into Deadpool in X-Men Origins: Wolverine?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, x-men-origins-wolverine

In *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, before being turned into Deadpool, Wade Wilson is seen to be able to handle swords with amazing skill, being able to deflect bullets with them. Even though this could be a sort of superpower, it isn't unthinkable to believe a very skilled human could do this in a fictional universe. Also, if this is a mutant power, what would it be, being able to move arms very fast?

Did Wade Wilson have mutant powers before being turned into Deadpool in *X-Men Origins*...?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The team that Stryker puts together are all mutants:

> STRYKER
> We're putting together a team. Best
> men in the business. Men with...
> special qualities. Men like you.
> — [Early Script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/X-Men-Origins-Wolverine.html)

Further Wade Wilson's abilities (before enhancement) are superhuman in the way they're portrayed - [deflecting bullets with a sword is possible](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ParryingBullets#folder12), but not at the speed Wade does this or with bullets that fast.

Add to that, that the Weapon programs (at least the ones seen in the film) use *mutants* as the base for their experimentation. It wouldn't make sense for them to deviate from this, and have to graft the superhuman abilities Wade shows from elsewhere.

Comment: Don't forget his greatest mutant power: breaking the fourth wall

Answer (score 6):

I have not found a definitive official statement, but every description of [Wade Wilson](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wade_Wilson_(Earth-10005)) and [Team X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_X_(comics)) indicates that he is a mutant on a team of mutants with his powers generally being simply listed as "enhanced reflexes".